# How to write a custom function in keras without using backend functions?

Tags: python, keras

I want to get the output of a keras layer which is a tensor of images, convert it to numpy arrays and apply a custom function on them without using backend functions, and return the output to the model. So it would be something like this:

```
def sum(args):
    # convert args to numpy arrays
    ???
    #calculating sum of all the elements
    s=np.sum(args)
    return s
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following format using `Keras` on `Tensorflow`:

```
  x = layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), strides=(1, 1), 
    padding='same', name='conv_1', use_bias=False)(input_image)
  x = my_function(x)
  x = layers.BatchNormalization(name='norm_1')(x)
```

Comment: It doesn't work like that. I already tried it. InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'input_19' with dtype float and shape [?,100]
  [[Node: input_19 = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[?,100], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]()]]